# Accessing/indexing in a 2-d dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has hourly values of energy accumulated, that span an entire month. I want to be able to plot the values of the accumulated energy by day. The first part of this is straightforward: I take the data frame and divide it by the column which defines the day, as shown below. I can also manually extract the value for each day I want, but I cannot automate this process using a for loop. This problem is described below.

```r
#Divide the data.frame into a list of data.frames 
#The column of the dataframe "vjk" which defines the date is called "Generated on" so that works for me

> daysvjk = split(vjkdata, f = vjkdata$`Generated On`)

#Let's now define a vector to hold the sums of daily values 
> dailyvaluesvjk <- vector(length = 30)

#I can access an individual value 
> dailyvaluesvjk[1] <- sum(daysvjk[[i]]$'Power Generated'

##but trying to automate this process gives only "FALSE"
> for(i in 1:30) {dailyvaluesvjk[i] = sum(daysvjk[[i]]$'Power Generated' )}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in `dailyvaluesvjk[i] = sum(daysvjk[[i]]` you have `=` instead of `<-`?

---

I take that back. I can't reproduce the problem.

Let's generate some data -- six days worth, with the first four days having two entries:

```
library("tidyverse")
set.seed(0)
dd <- data.frame(
  days=c(
    seq.Date(as.Date('2018-01-01'), as.Date('2018-01-6'), by = '1 day'),
    seq.Date(as.Date('2018-01-01'), as.Date('2018-01-4'), by = '1 day')), 
  powerGenerated=round(runif(10, 5, 10)))
dd <- arrange(dd, days)
```

(I have to assume this is the sort of data you're talking about. Provide sample data to make a good question.)

```
> dd
         days powerGenerated
1  2018-01-01              9
2  2018-01-01              9
3  2018-01-02              6
4  2018-01-02             10
5  2018-01-03              7
6  2018-01-03              8
7  2018-01-04              8
8  2018-01-04              8
9  2018-01-05             10
10 2018-01-06              6
```

Split into the list, and make the vector to hold the sums:

```
daysvjk <- split(dd, f=dd$days)
dailyvaluesvjk <- vector(length=length(daysvjk))
```

Make the sums inside a loop, and using the `=` for assignment:

```
for (i in 1:length(dailyvaluesvjk)) {
  dailyvaluesvjk[i] = sum(daysvjk[[i]]$powerGenerated)
}
```

Looks okay to me:

```
> dailyvaluesvjk
[1] 18 16 15 16 10  6
```

Are you sure you copied your code correctly? The `FALSE` makes me think maybe you have `dailyvaluesvjk[i] == sum(daysvjk[[i]]$'Power Generated' )`, using `==`?

Otherwise, make sure it's still happening, provide some sample data and what the output should be, and maybe we can have another stab.

(Two other notes: there are much more R-like (and easier) ways to do this, I'd look at `summarise` from the tidyverse. Also, if you need to pre-allocate vectors for performance, put `mode="numeric"` in there, otherwise it first allocates a vector of booleans.)

Comment: Thanks! I think you might be right. Can you tell me what the difference is?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your error. You should use `dput(vjkdata)` to make it easier for contributors.

It would be better to rename your fields so that there are no spaces. And you should check out aggregate.

```
aggregate(Power_Generated ~ days, data = DF, FUN = sum)
```

Here's the data I used and what I did to try to reproduce your error:

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(days = seq.Date(as.Date('2018-01-01'), as.Date('2018-02-01'), by = '1 day'),
                 Power_Generated = runif(32, 5, 10))

daysvjk <- split(DF, DF$days)

valuesVJK <- vector(length =32 )

#works
sum(daysvjk[[1]]$Power_Generated)

#works
for(i in 1:32) {valuesVJK[i] = sum(daysvjk[[i]]$Power_Generated )}
valuesVJK
```